Did Chevalley ever publish this paper?
In Sur Certains Groups Simples, Chevalley writes (and I translate) that 'we have applied analogous methods [to Dickson and Dieudonne's search for a condition which gives a simple group from a matrix group] to the cases of the exceptional groups $F_4$, $E_6$, and $E_7$ in a still unpublished work.'
I had thought that this was referring to his work The Exceptional Simple Lie Algebras F(4) and E(6), but it cannot be, since that was published first.
Is there a paper of Chevalley's which I haven't been able to find, published after 1955, which this is referring to?

Does the earlier paper contain an application of ‘analogous methods’? If so, could be a publisher’s lag.

I haven't read the earlier paper, so I will check, but that would be more than 6 years of delay.
